# PHP SoapServer always calls the same function despite calling different ones

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, soapserver

My SOAP server is (intended to be) setup with three operations: login, logout, and version.

The login function's code is currently "faking" it at the moment, accepting two parameters, a username and password, automatically "authenticating" them by storing them in the function class' private username and password variables. I have a session started at the entry point of the web service action, and when setting the function class in the SoapServer during initialization, I'm persisting connections as follows:

```
       $this->setClass('WebSvcSoapFunctions');
       $this->setPersistence(SOAP_PERSISTENCE_SESSION);
```

When I create a SOAP CLIENT and call my service, regardless of which function is called, it appears that the version() function is always executed rather than the one called. I imagine this is probably due to the way my WSDL is written, but I can't see a problem (i'm new)....

I have the following WSDL listening via a PHP SoapServer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<wsdl:types>

    <schema xmlns:rns="http://soap.jrimer-amp64/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://soap.jrimer-amp64/" version="1.0.0" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

        <complexType name="versionRequest">
        </complexType>

        <complexType name="versionResponse">
            <sequence>
                <element name="result" type="string" minOccurs="1"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>

        <complexType name="loginRequest">
            <sequence>
                <element name="username" type="string" use="required"/>
                <element name="password" type="string" use="required"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>

        <complexType name="loginResponse">
            <sequence>
                <element name="result" type="string" minOccurs="1"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>

        <complexType name="logoutRequest">
        </complexType>

        <complexType name="logoutResponse">
            <sequence>
                <element name="result" type="string" minOccurs="1"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>

    </schema>

</wsdl:types>


<wsdl:service name="XxxxxxSvc">

    <wsdl:port name="XxxxxxSvc-Endpoint0" binding="tns:XxxxxxSvc-Endpoint0Binding">
        <soap:address location="http://soap.jrimer-amp64/"/>
    </wsdl:port>

</wsdl:service>


<wsdl:portType name="portType">

    <wsdl:operation name="version">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:versionRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:versionResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="login">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:loginRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:loginResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="logout">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:logoutRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:logoutResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:portType>


<wsdl:binding name="XxxxxxSvc-Endpoint0Binding" type="tns:portType">

    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />

    <wsdl:operation name="version">
        <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="http://soap.jrimer-amp64/"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" parts="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" parts="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="login">
        <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="http://soap.jrimer-amp64/"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" parts="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" parts="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="logout">
        <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="http://soap.jrimer-amp64/"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" parts="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" parts="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:binding>


<wsdl:message name="versionRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns0:versionRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>


<wsdl:message name="versionResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns0:versionResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="loginRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns0:loginRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>


<wsdl:message name="loginResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns0:loginResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="logoutRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns0:logoutRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="logoutResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns0:logoutResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

My SOAP function class is as follows (included in my SOapServer via setClass()):

```
class WebSvcSoapFunctions
{
    private $username = ''; // username provided by the client during login() request
    private $password = ''; // password provided by the client during login() request

    /**
    * Handle a login request
    * 
    * @param string $user - Client's Username
    * @param string $pass - Client's Password
    */
    public function login($user,$pass)
    {
        $this->username = $user;
        $this->password = $pass;

        // should check for validity here, but for testing, return true.
        return 'Successful Login. Welcome, '.$user;
    }

    /**
    * Logs the client out.
    * 
    */
    public function logout()
    {
        $this->username = '';
        $this->password = '';
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
        return 'Logged Out Successfully.';
    }
        /**
    * checks if the client has logged in successfully
    * 
    * @return bool - true=logged in, false = unauthenticated
    */
    private function isAuthenticated()
    {
        if (isset($this->username) && $this->username != '')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Returns the version of the SOAP Server to the requesting client
    * 
    */
    public function version()
    {
        if ($this->isAuthenticated())
        {
            return 'Affinegy Service v1.0.0';
        }
        else
        {
            return 'NOT AUTHORIZED.';
        }
    }   
}
```

My SOAP CLIENT test class is as follows:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");  
define('WSDL_URL','http://soap.jrimer-amp64/?wsdl');   
try
{ 
    $client = new SoapClient(WSDL_URL, array('trace'=>true));

    $request = 'version';
    $args = array();
    $SOAPResult = $client->$request($args); // call the SOAP Server's "version" function
    OutputLastRequestResponse($client, $request, $args, $SOAPResult);

    $request = 'login';
    $args['username'] = 'testuser';
    $args['password'] = '1234';
    $SOAPResult = $client->$request($args); // call the SOAP Server's "login" function
    OutputLastRequestResponse($client, $request, $args, $SOAPResult);

    $request = 'version';
    $args = array();
    $SOAPResult = $client->$request($args); // call the SOAP Server's "version" function
    OutputLastRequestResponse($client, $request, $args, $SOAPResult);

    $request = 'logout';
    $args = array();
    $SOAPResult = $client->$request($args); // call the SOAP Server's "logout" function
    OutputLastRequestResponse($client, $request, $args, $SOAPResult);

    $request = 'version';
    $SOAPResult = $client->$request($args); // call the SOAP Server's "version" function
    OutputLastRequestResponse($client, $request, $args, $SOAPResult);

}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo '<pre>FAILED: '.print_r($e,1).'</pre>'; // dump the client exception to screen

    OutputLastRequestResponse($client);
}

/**
* Displays the request and response of the test service call
* 
* @param SoapServer $client - Object of type SoapClient that does the request
* @param string $requested - name of the SOAP function called
* @param array $args - Arguments sent to the SOAP function
* @param string $returned - PHP readable value returned by the client calling the provided SOAP function
*/
function OutputLastRequestResponse($client, $requested = '', $args=array(), $returned='')
{
    echo '<h1>XXXXXXXX SERVICE SOAP SERVER TEST</h1>';
    echo 'Request: <pre>'.$requested.'</pre>';
    echo 'Request Arguments: <pre>'.print_r($args,1).'</pre>';
    echo 'Returned: <pre>'.$returned.'</pre>';
    echo 'Raw Request: <pre>'.htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequestHeaders());
    echo htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()).'</pre>';
    echo 'Raw Response: <pre>'.htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponseHeaders())."\n";
    echo htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse()).'</pre>';
}
```

The results from the test class runs are as follows... Notice "NOT AUTHORIZED." is the response to everything, indicating that ONLY the WebSvcSoapFunctions::version() function is running

> Xxxxxx SERVICE SOAP SERVER TEST
>   Request:
>
> version
>
> Request Arguments:
>
> Array ( )
>
> Returned:
>
> NOT AUTHORIZED.
>
> Raw Request:
>
> POST / HTTP/1.1 Host:
>   soap.jrimer-amp64 Connection:
>   Keep-Alive User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.2.10
>   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>   SOAPAction:
>   "http://soap.jrimer-amp64/"
>   Content-Length: 227
>
> Raw Response:
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 16 Jun 2011
>   19:43:32 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.3
>   (CentOS) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.10
>   Set-Cookie:
>   PHPSESSID=scbuin269990ahfargfq7k0972;
>   path=/ Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981
>   08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store,
>   no-cache, must-revalidate,
>   post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma:
>   no-cache Content-Length: 209
>   Connection: close Content-Type:
>   text/xml; charset=utf-8
>
> NOT
>   AUTHORIZED.
>
> Xxxxxx SERVICE SOAP SERVER TEST
>   Request:
>
> login
>
> Request Arguments:
>
> Array (
>       [username] => jrimer
>       [password] => 1234 )
>
> Returned:
>
> NOT AUTHORIZED.
>
> Raw Request:
>
> POST / HTTP/1.1 Host:
>   soap.jrimer-amp64 Connection:
>   Keep-Alive User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.2.10
>   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>   SOAPAction:
>   "http://soap.jrimer-amp64/"
>   Content-Length: 298 Cookie:
>   PHPSESSID=scbuin269990ahfargfq7k0972;
>
> usernamejrimerpassword1234
>
> Raw Response:
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 16 Jun 2011
>   19:43:32 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.3
>   (CentOS) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.10
>   Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>   Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache,
>   must-revalidate, post-check=0,
>   pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache
>   Content-Length: 209 Connection: close
>   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>
> NOT
>   AUTHORIZED.
>
> Xxxxxx SERVICE SOAP SERVER TEST
>   Request:
>
> version
>
> Request Arguments:
>
> Array ( )
>
> Returned:
>
> NOT AUTHORIZED.
>
> Raw Request:
>
> POST / HTTP/1.1 Host:
>   soap.jrimer-amp64 Connection:
>   Keep-Alive User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.2.10
>   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>   SOAPAction:
>   "http://soap.jrimer-amp64/"
>   Content-Length: 227 Cookie:
>   PHPSESSID=scbuin269990ahfargfq7k0972;
>
> Raw Response:
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 16 Jun 2011
>   19:43:32 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.3
>   (CentOS) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.10
>   Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>   Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache,
>   must-revalidate, post-check=0,
>   pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache
>   Content-Length: 209 Connection: close
>   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>
> NOT
>   AUTHORIZED.
>
> Xxxxxx SERVICE SOAP SERVER TEST
>   Request:
>
> logout
>
> Request Arguments:
>
> Array ( )
>
> Returned:
>
> NOT AUTHORIZED.
>
> Raw Request:
>
> POST / HTTP/1.1 Host:
>   soap.jrimer-amp64 Connection:
>   Keep-Alive User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.2.10
>   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>   SOAPAction:
>   "http://soap.jrimer-amp64/"
>   Content-Length: 227 Cookie:
>   PHPSESSID=scbuin269990ahfargfq7k0972;
>
> Raw Response:
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 16 Jun 2011
>   19:43:32 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.3
>   (CentOS) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.10
>   Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>   Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache,
>   must-revalidate, post-check=0,
>   pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache
>   Content-Length: 209 Connection: close
>   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>
> NOT
>   AUTHORIZED.
>
> Xxxxxx SERVICE SOAP SERVER TEST
>   Request:
>
> version
>
> Request Arguments:
>
> Array ( )
>
> Returned:
>
> NOT AUTHORIZED.
>
> Raw Request:
>
> POST / HTTP/1.1 Host:
>   soap.jrimer-amp64 Connection:
>   Keep-Alive User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.2.10
>   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>   SOAPAction:
>   "http://soap.jrimer-amp64/"
>   Content-Length: 227 Cookie:
>   PHPSESSID=scbuin269990ahfargfq7k0972;
>
> Raw Response:
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 16 Jun 2011
>   19:43:32 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.3
>   (CentOS) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.10
>   Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>   Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache,
>   must-revalidate, post-check=0,
>   pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache
>   Content-Length: 209 Connection: close
>   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>
> NOT
>   AUTHORIZED.

Any ideas what's going on?

NOTE: I notice that if I simply comment out the definition in the WSDL for the VERSION function that the next defined function becomes the "always called" function (login)... What do I have configured wrong in that WSDL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it was the WSDL, I completely have it misdefined... Restructured the WSDL and it fields requests correctly now...

Comment: I am having the same problem, can you tell what you did to fix it, thanks